# Do multiple link.xml files conflict in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, il2cpp

Files named link.xml are used to prevent certain codes being "bytecode stripped with IL2CPP" (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-BytecodeStripping.html).

I have two 3rd party SDKs in my Unity project, both have a link.xml file in their own folder. I worry if they conflict with each other? Should I combine their contents together into one single link.xml file?

Comment: split one that you know works in to two link.xml files and see if it still works. I have multiple and it seems to work fine

Comment: I can't test it now because I don't have a 100% way to test and tell if the link.xml file works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple link.xml files will work correctly. Unity will preserve the all of the types and methods in all of the link.xml files in the project.